# CI: Jquery Pop-up

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, popup

I’m working with HTML/Jquery code that our designer passed over to me so that I can integrate CI into it. The problem I’m having is that certain links use jquery to pop open light boxes, but once put into CI these no longer work.  If I point the link to a controller, then load the pop up view, it simply loads the pop as an entire page, not a simple shadow box.

I've looked at the CI anchor_pop...is this the correct thing to use?  In other words, as it stands, when using the code provided by the designer, the pop up opens perfectly (centered, sized-right, etc). In using the anchor_pop, while it calls my page, it also opens it up funky.  Is there an easy way to simply call the page/jquery function as my designer has it set up as shown below? Thanks.

A code snippet from my view is as follows:

jquery:

```
$(function(){
$('form').jqTransform();
});
$(window).load(function  () {
$(".join-button a").fancybox().trigger('click');
});
```

Link:

```
<li class="join-button"><a href="pupup1.html">join</a></li>
```

Edited:
I attempted the suggested removal of .trigger('click'), but no luck.  Below is an image of what I want to happen, along with an image of what happens:

[image: Popup]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
$(window).load(function  () {
    $(".join-button a").fancybox();
});
```

if you `.trigger('click')` you simulate a simple click on the link and so you are taken to that page

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the code into the `$(window).load()` function.  Fancybox is a jQuery plugin so it should be used within the regular `$(document).ready()` function.

Nicola is right though, you don't want to trigger click on the element.  Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').jqTransform();
    $(".join-button a").fancybox();
});
```

Assuming you have all of your JS files loaded correctly, this should work.

Comment: thanks, that's getting me closer.  While I'm getting the fancybox to fire, its not loading the actual page.  I've got the actual html (or will be php in this case) page in my Views folder...I still need to be able to access it to pass data to and from, but how should I reference it in the code since a simple a href doesn't seem to be working, and using anchor_pop causes a new window to open?  Thanks again.

Comment: When you say you're using "anchor_pop" do you mean that you are using CodeIgniter's "anchor_popup" method from the URL helper?  If yes, that might be conflicting with Fancybox because it puts an onclick attribute on the link with some inline JS.